# Any dangers of modifying an existing migration file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

A company I recently started working for have, at some point in time, managed to delete one of their migration files - or at least that is what I believe. This file created a table of let's say `users`, but this table has since been removed.

I would normally not mind had it not been for the fact that building the project locally will fail unless I temporarily shoehorn in an early migration that includes this table creation, this is because there are later migrations that both modify columns on this supposed `users` table and eventually removes the table. What I have done recently is just add it to an existing migration file that was creating some other table, let's say `products`, which I have been "carrying" around from branch to branch being real careful that I don't commit it.

It looks something like this (examples):

```rb
class AddProductsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
    end
  end
end
```

Which I have changed to:

```rb
class AddProductsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
    end

    create_table :users do |t|
    end
  end
end
```

I am essentially wondering if committing this would do any harm on production. After all, the migration has already been run so it wouldn't execute it again? I'm very tempted to just do this as it's getting old real fast to always remember to recreate or lug this piece of code around when I need to rebuild, but I don't feel confident enough that something bad won't happen nor have I found much in the way of answers on Google.

*PS., I'm the only developer on the project currently and they don't have any other developers who I could ask this question to.*

Comment: Why are you running all those migrations when you could just load the schema and start fresh?

Comment: It is (common) practice, at a certain time, to squash migrations into one, that just loads schema.rb (or structure.sql). To start locally, use `rake db:setup` which will create the database and load the complete schema (instead of doing `rake db:migrate` --it will be a lot quicker).

Comment: @muistooshort pretty much because I didn't even know I could :S shows how much I know I guess haha

Comment: @nathanvda thanks for the good info :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the migration has been ran in production, this should not cause any issues in the production environment. You could even [delete](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#old-migrations) it if you must (Note: not recommended if you have other team members as they will face the issue you are facing if they haven't already ran the migration locally).

To check whether a migration has been ran in a given environment you can use the following rake command:

```
RAILS_ENV=<environment> bundle exec rake db:migrate:status
```

For example, doing this in development you will get this:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:migrate:status
   up     20190201100000  Add soups table
   up     20190301100000  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190601100000  Add supplies table
   up     20190501100000  Remove food column from supplies table
   up     20190601100000  Add test table
   up     20190701100000  Add foo column to test
   up     20190801100000  Add products table
   down   20191119030000  I havent ran this
```

The above tells you which migrations have been ran (indicated by **up**) and which haven't been ran (indicated by **down**). It also tells you whether there is a file associated with the migration or if the file has been deleted (see the one above with no file). When you deploy your project to production, the **down** migrations will be ran so modifying the **up** migrations will not do anything.

I recommend you run the following in production to make sure the migration you are modifying has the **down** status.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate:status
```

Comment: Great suggestion to use `rake db:migrate:status` to see which migration was run and deleted and maybe could be restored (from git? git bisect comes to mind). Manually editing migrations that have been run in general make my spidey senses tingle, and I would generally advice against it. But this might work.

Comment: I like this answer. I feel this is as good of an answer as I can expect given my question's somewhat ambiguous nature. This, together with possible squashing/restoring mentioned by @nathanvda, should probably lead me to the results I want. :) Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't already ran the migration, then no problem editing the migration file. **Otherwise**:
Quoting from rails guides:

> In general, editing existing migrations is not a good idea. You will be creating extra work for yourself and your co-workers and cause major headaches if the existing version of the migration has already been run on production machines. Instead, you should write a new migration that performs the changes you require. Editing a freshly generated migration that has not yet been committed to source control (or, more generally, which has not been propagated beyond your development machine) is relatively harmless.

Source: [Changing existing migrations](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-existing-migrations)